# Replacing the formulae in dataframe (pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[sample csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT6HR.png)I have a .csv file which has many columns consisting of formulas like this:
="010",
="011"
By default when I am storing it to a pandas dataframe, the formulas are stored as it is. Can anyone help me like how to convert these values in whole dataframe to values:
010,
011

Comment: Could you show an example of your csv file or the dataframe from the csv file?

Comment: pls check the same csv hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom function.

Here is a very basic example that should work with the data you have shown.

```
def to_float(item):
    return float(item[1:].strip('"'))

df['COUNTRY CODE'] = df['COUNTRY CODE'].apply(to_float)
```

The function `to_float()` is just an example, you shall decide how to implement the custom function to do the transformation.